# What are the advantages of creating custom CSS responsive architecture / framework?

Tags: css, responsive-design, frameworks

We’re debating the responsive CSS solution (Zurb Foundation vs. custom) to be used for the future company projects. I’d like to ask the community: "Who is using custom responsive CSS architecture and why?"

Comment: Zurb Foundation is just a framework. There are tons of it online. A lot of people tend to build off these frameworks because they don't want to rewrite/rethink code that's already being done. That being said, those front-end frameworks may not do everything that you want, so you'll have to add your own custom css.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom css framework, you can extend the Foundation according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you all for taking a few minutes and post your Feedback. To make it more scientific, I wanted to evaluate the CSS framework on a set of attributes like effort, and performance. It would be great if you could provide your input on these attributes. It should take LESS THAN A MINUTE. Feel free to forward it.

https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/5rh9rjt

I will share the results of this survey in this discussion, once its completed.